# Cox PH Modelling: How important are ties to the end result?

Tags: survival, cox-model, approximation, hazard

I am working on create a survival model using Cox PH, but am concerned with the limitation of the continuous time requirement. In my dataset there are often ties. For example, out of 35000 records, 500 of them die at 1000, 400 of them die at 500, and 300 of them die at 5000. 7500 of my records are part of a group of deaths/ties that all died/tie at the same time with 10 or more records.

From what I can tell, Efron's approximation to maximizing likelihood is sufficient in MOST practical applications, but it seems that the amount of ties in my data may be too much.

I am fitting the Cox PH model in R and having difficulty matching the predicted values to the quantiles and mean of the actual dataset, I was thinking the above could be an issue.

Is Efron's approximation going to work with my data?

Comment: Did you also try the Breslow approximation along with the exact method? How do the results differ?

Comment: I tried the Breslow method as well, the results were different (obviously), but still did not give reasonable results. I didn't save the results (should have...). I have been running the Exact method with Revo R in a pretty sophisticated setup for over 20 hours, not sure if it will ever finish.